# UseHiLo with value converter?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a struct that wraps an int as such:

```
    public struct LongId
    {
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }
      
    // Model
    public class TestEntity
    {
        public LongId Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in my context's OnCreating method:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
        {
            mb.Entity<TestEntity>()
                .Property(o => o.Id)
                .HasConversion(o => o.Value, l => new LongId{Value = l})
                .UseHiLo();
        }
```

However, when trying to run migrations, I get the following error:

> SQL Server sequences cannot be used to generate values for the property 'Id' on entity type 'TestEntity' because the property type is 'LongId'. Sequences can only be used with integer properties.

How can I make this work?

Comment: *"How can I make this work?"* The error message is telling you that you *cannot*. Consider it current EF Core limitation. The same applies for auto-increment (identity) properties.